# "Reloading tor daemon configuration... fail" after updating torrc

Tags: configuration, relays

I'm running a relay node on my box, and I recently updated the `torrc` file (I set a `RelayBandwidthRate` and commented out `AccountingMax`)

I then run:

`$ service tor reload`

and this is the output:

`* Reloading tor daemon configuration...                 [fail]`

Comment: Try running with the `--verify-config` flag and see if it throws up anything useful. (i.e `tor --verify-config`).

Comment: I just ran `$ tor --verify-config`, and it spits back: `Configuration was valid`.

Comment: Permissions issue? What happens if you run it with `sudo`?

Comment: If I run it with `sudo` I get the same `Configuration was valid` message.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the reload command: `sudo service tor reload`

Comment: No joy, I still get this: `* Reloading tor daemon configuration...   [fail]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33775/discussion-between-richard-horrocks-and-eric).

Comment: Use Tor from official git sources - I have had similar issues myself. Ubuntu-packaged version fails alot - Git one no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update from associated chat session.]

The relay had hit its accounting limits and entered [hibernate mode](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#LimitTotalBandwidth).

To bring the service back up it was necessary to `restart` it instead of `reload` it.

`$ service tor restart`

Comment: pretty weird, because when it reaches it's accounting limits - it reloads it's config and restarts OK